# Warnings When Using Leaps for Model Selection

Tags: r

I recently tried using `leaps` on a large data set by running `leaps=regsubsets(TOTAL~.,data=TASM,nbest=10)` based on the code found on the first page [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~martin/W2024/R10.pdf).  I initially got the error `Exhaustive search will be S L O W, must specify really.big=T` so I added that in at the end `leaps=regsubsets(TOTAL~.,data=TASM,nbest=10, really.big=T)`.

I now receive the warning that `In leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax, force.in = force.in,  : 83  linear dependencies found`.  Since this is a warning I assumed that it is not going to stop me from running the model selection algorithm but nothing happens after the warning.  What is the purpose of `leaps` warning me about the number of linear dependencies and should it generally be resolved before running the algorithm?  If not, how can I tell `leaps` to run the algorithm anyway?

UPDATE: I realize this is a less useful question than I thought initially.  My lack of experience with R had me forgetting to call `summary(leaps)`.  As a follow-up though, are the results of this telling me the best models from 1 to 10?  That is, the top model posted below with V1...V7 selected is the best according to `leaps`?  From using `plot(leaps,scale="adjr2")` and receiving a blank plot I am led to believe that there is an error somewhere.  The warning message is: `In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`.

```
         V1           V2         V3             V4        V5   V6      V7
1  ( 1 ) " "         " "        " "            " "       " "  " "     " "             
1  ( 2 ) " "         " "        " "            " "       " "  " "     " "             
1  ( 3 ) " "         " "        " "            " "       " "  " "     " "             
1  ( 4 ) " "         " "        " "            " "       " "  " "     " "             
1  ( 5 ) " "         " "        " "            " "       " "  " "     " "             
1  ( 6 ) " "         " "        " "            " "       " "  " "     " "             
1  ( 7 ) " "         " "        " "            " "       " "  " "     " "             
1  ( 8 ) " "         " "        "*"            " "       " "  " "     " "
```